# Threshold Value for Network connectivity status of Resources Apim Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management, apim

I am trying to create Alert in APIM of Azure and choosed
**Network Connectivity status of Resources**

I am stuck in determining threshold value in the APIM for this metric
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Can you let me know what count and average to set, also what is threshold value to set on is it resource or number of requests for the APIM service

Answer (score 0):

This metric is published with two additional dimensions: region and resource type. In that view you can investigate those dimensions if you use "Apply splitting" option. The metric publishes "1" for every resource type every location every minute if resource is reachable, and "0" if it is not. Sum aggregation would generally just count number of positive checks, and Avg would be an average of those.

So as a threshold you could use average aggregation and set it to "1", because if even one of the resources becomes not available "0" will be recorded and Average will drop to 0.9 or similar and alert will trigger.